# GLSL - why can't index array with a `uint64_t`?

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I have this GLSL code that compiles fine:

```
#version 450
#extension GL_EXT_shader_explicit_arithmetic_types_int64 : enable

layout (local_size_x = 256) in;

layout(binding = 1) buffer OutBuffer {
    uint64_t outBuf[];
};

void main()
{
    uint myId = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
    outBuf[myId] = 0;
}
```

If I change the type of `myId` from `uint` to `uint64_t` it doesn't compile:

```
ERROR: calc.comp.glsl:13: '[]' : scalar integer expression required
```

I can just use `uint`, but I'm curious why you can't use `uint64_t`.

Comment: because OpenGL GLSL does not know what `uint64_t` is ... see [GLSL data types](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Scalars) ... on Vulcan I do not know but doubt they changed shader compilers implementations ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything other than `uint` or `int` needs to be explicitly casted to one of these types when used for indexing arrays:

```
uint64_t myId = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
outBuf[uint(myId)] = 0;
```

The [spec](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/blob/master/extensions/ext/GL_EXT_shader_explicit_arithmetic_types.txt) `GL_EXT_shader_explicit_arithmetic_types_***` doesn't seem to say anything about using the types it introduces to index arrays.

It defines implicit promotion rules such as `uint16_t` -> `uint32_t` (defined to be equivalent to `uint`).
and these of course work for function parameters,
but curiously you can't even use `uint16_t` as an array index and expect it to be implicitly promoted to 'uint32_t'; you need to explicitly cast it to `uint` (or `uint32_t`).

So we're at the mercy of the original GLSL spec when indexing arrays; use `uint` or `sint`, which are the only scalar integer types it knows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know you can't use `uint16_t` neither, very interesting.

Comment: What if we have a very large (>4G) array?